# Working of button click inside loops, while or foreach

Tags: php, forms, loops, while-loop

```php
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="sb">
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($i<10) {  
        if(isset($_REQUEST['sb'])) {
            echo $i;
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
</form>
```

I got `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` when the button is clicked.

I expect `9` to be the result but how `0 to 9`?

How is this click event processed when inside there is a loop?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, while loop is executing in both cases before button pressed and after button pressed and also you have printed *i* in the while loop that's why you are getting *0* to *9* as result.

Try the following code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="sb">
<?php
$i=0;     
if(isset($_REQUEST['sb']))
{
    while ($i<10)
    {
        $i++;
    }
    echo $i;
}

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it